# TeX capacity exceeded with \boldsymbol

Tags: sectioning, bold, boldmath

It is happening something really strange. I know that many people have this error for different reasons and I am here to add another one.

I wrote a document with a certain section which is called

```
 \section{First derivative of $\boldsymbol{\beta}_{ij}$}
```

The command works all over the document but when I have it in the `\section` title it gives me the error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
```

It is a problem of the `\boldsymbol` command I think because if I remove it, it works fine. Someone can help me?

EDIT: It is also strange that this works flawlessly

```
\section{First derivative of $\beta$}
$\boldsymbol{\beta}_{ij}$
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: It works for me when I try it. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: presumably you have the equivalent of `\renewcommand\boldsymbol[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}` in some code you have not shown.

Comment: Why the `stack` tag?

Comment: @samcarter sorry you are right

Comment: @minidiable Will we get a MWE instead?

Comment: The problem is that, as written by many of you, the code works without any problems with the MWE in the answer below. I don't why it doesn't work in my document. I can't share the whole document because it is a phd thesis. I will try to investigate more and come back here.

Comment: @minidiable See [this answer to “I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?”](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/48) which will tell you how to turn your PhD thesis into a smaller example.

Answer (score 2):

Works without problems.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\section{First derivative of $\boldsymbol{\beta}_{ij}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is really strange. For me it continues to not work. I checked everywhere. There is no redefinition of \boldsymbol . 

The first occurence of \boldsymbol I have in my document is 
\newcommand{\nullProj}{\boldsymbol{P}}

Comment: @minidiable then update your question with exactly which mwe are are testing with. You can start with Henris example here. Also note exactly which engine you use to compile, pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex, and if possible provide the log file.

Comment: @minidiable Step one: try the minimal working example from this answer. In case this works for you: next step, produce a minimal document that demonstrates your problem